# How to Use npm cache on Server with Multiple Build Agents

Tags: node.js, npm, msbuild, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I'd like to use npm on an on-premises Windows server hosting multiple TFS 2015 Build Agents. The agents themselves are set up and configured already, and npm has been installed on the server. The issue that concerns me is the possibility of npm cache collisions and possible corruption if multiple agents are accessing the npm cache at the same time for different builds. All agents must run under the same service account, so even if I override the `cache` setting in the user config `.npmrc` file located at `%USERPROFILE%\.npmrc`, this will still have all build agents using the same npm cache location (since they're all using the same account and thus use the same .npmrc file). Is there a way to specify an npm cache for each agent on the same machine, such that each agent folder could have its own nested npm-cache sub-folder (and would be used only by builds executed by that respective agent)?

Comment: did you try to run some builds at the same time and check if it doing corruption?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I haven't tried on this current server, but I've seen it happen before on a previous build server that hosted multiple TFS XAML build agents. I'm trying to prevent that from happening this time around. :-)

Comment: I am very interested to know if you found a solution to this problem! We're in a situation where each build agent (on the same box) now runs under it's own account, however we're getting occasional conflicts on the global install of npm which resides in Program FIles rather than a user area.

Comment: @JThorpe No direct resolution to this issue, so I changed the way we run builds. Now, we use containers in our build process, so that when a project is being built and npm dependencies are installed, everything happens inside a container. That side-steps the collision issue since each container's npm install has no effect on that of other containers.